# Only one Kafka consumer is getting data

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

There is one Kubernetes property called replica, suppose  we have  `3` replicas(`replica-0`, `replica-1`, `replica-2`) and we are producing 100 messages in Kafka, Only one replica say (`replica-0`) is invoked at a time for consuming all the 100 messages, but the expected solution is all the 100 messages should be divided among 3 replicas(`replica-0`, `replica-1`, `replica-2`) instead keeping the load on one replica for consuming the messages

Comment: How is the post programming-related?

Answer (score 1):

You should clarify "invoked". Consumers poll; they are not externally "invoked"/started other than calling `poll()` method.

Consumers configured with the same `group.id` cannot subscribe to overlapping partitions. If you sent 100 records to one partition, then only one consumer will read that. If you want all applications to read a subset of the data, then you first will need a Kafka topic with at least 3 partitions (the default auto-created topics only have one), then send data amongst those.

Kubernetes has nothing to do with the Kafka consumer subscription.